# How to set response model as a class in Springfox Swagger?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I using `OperationBuilderPlugin` of Springfox Swagger to process some custom written annotations. However, for operation related annotations, I need to specify response model as well.

Now, response model requires a `ModelReference` object. I want to set the class that is actually returned from the endpoint as a response. However, it does not recognize that. I have seen people only putting values like `string`, `Error`, etc.

Here's some code.

My operations related plugin's troublemaking piece of code.

```java
context.operationBuilder()
        .summary(...)
        .produces(...)
        .consumes(...)
        .responseModel(new ModelRef("DefaultResponse")).build()
```

My `DefaultResponse` class has nothing special. It's just a POJO.

```java
@ApiModel
class DefaultResponse {
        private String message;
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, we can add additional models to our `Docket` definition. So, adding `additionalModels(typeResolver.resolve (DefaultResponse.class) )` to the bean definition solved it. We can autowire the `com.fasterxml.classmate.TypeResolver` object.

I found the answer [here](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1006#issuecomment-438689432)